# CentOS 7 Jenkins Clean Install Fails

Tags: java, jenkins, installation, groovy

I have made a clean Jenkins installation (`Jenkins v2.240`) on CentOS 7 with `openjdk version "1.8.0_252"`. After starting Jenkins I get following WARNING LOG, and server gives 500 when I try to access

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Conflicting module versions. Module [groovy-all is loaded in version 2.4.12 and you are trying to load version 2.4.8
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$DefaultModuleListener.onModule(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:513)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromProperties(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanExtensionModuleFromMetaInf(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.ExtensionModuleScanner.scanClasspathModules(ExtensionModuleScanner.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:74)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
Caused: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:66)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.<init>(GroovyObjectSupport.java:34)
    at groovy.lang.Binding.<init>(Binding.java:35)
    at jenkins.util.groovy.GroovyHookScript.<init>(GroovyHookScript.java:42)
    at hudson.init.impl.GroovyInitScript.init(GroovyInitScript.java:42)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

After request it prints following log:

```
2020-07-03 11:53:30.965+0000 [id=98]    WARNING o.e.jetty.server.HttpChannel#handleException: /
org.apache.commons.jelly.JellyTagException: jar:file:/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.240.jar!/lib/layout/layout.jelly:96:72: <st:include> Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.handleException(TagScript.java:745)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:289)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
        at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:63)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:53)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:56)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:43)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Facet$1.dispatch(Facet.java:238)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:747)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:878)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:676)
        at hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.handleException(InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:67)
        at hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.lambda$init$0(InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:36)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.reportException(CompressionFilter.java:77)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
        at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
        at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
        at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1604)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)
```

I tried it with many jenkins versions, including LTS(2.235.1). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jenkins-for-continuous-development-integration-on-centos-7

Comment: That's what i did.